# Can you fund your Traditional IRA after rolling it over to Roth IRA?

Tags: united-states, roth-ira, rollover, roth-conversion

The Traditional IRA has a $6,000 limit per year. If I

Step1: Transfer 6k to Traditional IRA
Step2: Roll over entire 6k to Roth IRA

Can I transfer additional 6k to Traditional IRA because Traditional IRA is "empty" after rolling over to Roth IRA?

Comment: You already contributed $6,000 to the IRA. The rollover doesn't change that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to think of it is contributions vs. conversions/transfers. The contributions are limited to $6k for each tax year, regardless of what transfers you make.